# Can I keep hashed passwords after a migration to a new databse structure?

Tags: php, cakephp, hash, passwords, migration

I made a website time ago. Raw php with SQL. Now I am doing a new version with CakePHP, this implies a lot of conventions that I want to follow, that is, I'd like to keep things the cakePHP way as much as possible.

But:

There is a users table that I am trying to split into two new ones on the new version, adding fields and dividing user identification fields and usage statistics fields, I am still looking for the best way to do this easy, this is not the main question but any help will be appreciated. The table name is different to adjust to convention, and fields have changed. I still have to do some research of this.

The old site used sha1() to hash passwords and I want to know if there is any chance of keeping the records without making all the users register again.

I found some cracking tips to do it faster than brute force. Well, they say they are faster, but I have about 1000 users. Besides, I don't think it's legal nor ethical to crack my users passwords to make my work easier. So cracking seems to be out of the question.

I thought of just copying the records as they are and set a "reset password" for them, so they can just log in again with a code sent to the email they provided when registering. This is not a very bad option, but I'd like to do it only if there's no other way.

Well, is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Why not just loop over your old table inserting the users back the new one while setting the new fields to their default value(s) (and/or request the information when the user logs in)? Why do you need to know their unhashed password in order to copy it? (assuming you are going to be using the same hashing algorithm)

Comment: The algorithm is one that is not recommended anymore. Security hasn't been an issue yet in this site, so I suppose I can keep the old one. I'll just check how to change that in cakephp and give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you would crack the SHA-1 hashes, you wouldn't be sure if you found the real password or only a collision. So you could not rehash these found passwords with a different hash algorithm.

It's not necessary to reset the passwords, you can just wait until the user logs in the next time.

1. Then you can first check for the new algorithm.
2. If it does not match, compare it with the old SHA-1 hash.
3. Should the old hash value match, then you can calculate and store the new hash, since you know the real password then.

Every password-storing-system must have the option to switch to a better hash algorithm, your problem is not a one-time migrating problem. Good password hash algorithms like **BCrypt** have a cost factor, from time to time you have to increase this cost factor (because of faster hardware), then you need the exact same procedure as you need for the migration.

I really recommend to switch to a slow key-derivation function like BCrypt, instead of the fast hash algorithms like SHA-1 or even SHA-256, because they are ways too fast and can be brute forced too easily ([3 Giga SHA-1 values](http://hashcat.net/oclhashcat-lite/#performance) per second in 2013).

Answer (score 3):

You can keep your existing passwords if you want. Just make a [custom Authenticate class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects) for AuthComponent and override relevant method to use the hashing scheme you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reset passwords or apply at your new system the same hashing algorithm as it was on previous one.